# Windows 10 non admin install

Tags: windows-10, administrator, windows-domain, non-admin

I was at school today and saw something weird I wanted an explanation of how it works. So we can't install any programs on the school laptops, and someone at my school tried to install Roblox. I thought it will never work but then I saw Roblox was installing, so I tried it and to my surprise, it worked. So we tried steam and that one didn't work. How could this be ??

Some info
The laptops run Windows 10
and uses windows domain
Microsoft store is installed and working
but he didn't install it from there

Comment: It could be that your school only matches the Steam executable. Have you asked your teacher or IT helpdesk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install Steam you need Admin rights. But Roblox is Java based and can be executed without any Admin rights. That is the reason it worked.

Comment: Basically, admin rights are only required to write to certain parts of the system, and Roblox doesn't have to write anywhere special in order to run.

Answer (score 2):

(Some) Apps that install themselves onto the user's `AppData` do not require administrator rights as any app with the user's access tokens can access that folder.

Only apps run with an administrator access token can write to the Program Files folder.

Steam puts itself in `Program Files (x86)`, requiring administrator privileges.
Roblox puts itself in AppData\Local, so it does not require administrator priveleges.

Note that if you first run the Roblox installer with Administrator rights, it will instead install to `Program Files`, requiring Roblox to be run with Administrator every subsequent time in order for it to work as it requires access to that folder.